# Writing text on 8-bit bitmap with PyQt

Tags: python, qt, image-processing, bitmap, pyqt

I've got an indexed colour (up to 6 colours) 8 bit bitmap file.

I need to write some text on it and save without changing the format nor the colour table.

Unfortunately via docs:
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html

> Note: Drawing into a QImage with QImage::Format_Indexed8 is not supported.

My attempt was to open the file as QImage, convert to a format I can write on with QPainter (using only colours which are already in the colour table) and then convert it back to an 8-bit bitmap.

Something like this:

```
image = image.convertToFormat(QImage.Format_RGB16)
painter = QPainter()
painter.begin(image)
[....]
painter.end()
image = image.convertToFormat(QImage.Format_Indexed8, Qt.ThresholdDither)
```

But no matter what I do I always end up with a somehow corrupted image (it has 4 bit colour depth, it's damaged with kind of a noise in it, or it has its colours changed).

I've tried using different flags during conversion (usually messes the colour depth).

I also tried to copy the colorTable from the original image and set it after the conversion (before save) but this produces a negative/black&white image.

I would be very grateful for any help with this issue.

Comment: Are you aware of what Indexed8 actually means? It means the pixels don't have colours but refer to palette indices. I don't know anything about python, but you should access the underlying array of the image and just edit it by giving the entries on that array (normally one byte per pixel) values that refer to different indices on the palette.

Comment: As for the noise, I imagine that's because you tell it to dither the image, with `ThresholdDither`.